# Alloy user interface (selector)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I'm working with lifaray portal 6.2. And I want to get all checked checkboxes inside of a  with alloy user interface. I tried `A.one('#myDiv>:checkbox:checked')` but it didn't work. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `A.all('#myDiv input:checked')` and if you want to check length try with: `A.all('#myDiv input:checked').size();`.